# Python pandas transformation of different versions of a number into one

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I work in pandas with large phone connection reports of over 100,000 lines. Like this:
[image]

The problem is that the phone numbers in these reports are spelled out differently. For example: 8869836, 298869836, 359298869836 is the same number, but written in the easy, domestic and international formats. If I apply grouping (groupby) by phone numbers, I will get incorrect results, since different forms of the same number will be perceived by pandas as different numbers. Therefore, I decided to create an additional series in which to enter the longest version of numbers, like this:

[image]

But I have no idea how to make such a transformation quickly and efficiently. Maybe someone has some ideas?

Add code for working example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
['2021-05-31 10-51-04', 23, 'tel-out', '3302037'],
['2021-05-31 11-04-06', 71, 'tel-out', '298869836'],
['2021-05-31 11-07-07', 21, 'tel-out', '8869836'],
['2021-05-31 11-21-54', 53, 'tel-out', '333468650'],
['2021-05-31 11-23-06', 96, 'tel-in', '359333468650'],
['2021-05-31 13-21-23', 9, 'tel-out', '3468650'],
['2021-05-31 14-33-18', 1, 'sms-in', '870'],
['2021-05-31 15-06-28', 55, 'tel-out', '298869836'],
['2021-05-31 15-07-36', 1, 'sms-in', '359298869836'],
['2021-05-31 15-07-50', 71, 'tel-out', '359333182504'],
['2021-05-31 15-13-18', 22, 'tel-out', '3182504']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['F0', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3'])
df
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the input data in text form (so we can copy-paste it)?

Comment: I load data from bif csv-files, but for working example add to my question code for dinamically dataframe creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["F3-1"] = df.groupby(df["F3"].str[-7:])["F3"].transform(
    lambda x: max(x, key=len)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                     F0  F1       F2            F3          F3-1
0   2021-05-31 10-51-04  23  tel-out       3302037       3302037
1   2021-05-31 11-04-06  71  tel-out     298869836  359298869836
2   2021-05-31 11-07-07  21  tel-out       8869836  359298869836
3   2021-05-31 11-21-54  53  tel-out     333468650  359333468650
4   2021-05-31 11-23-06  96   tel-in  359333468650  359333468650
5   2021-05-31 13-21-23   9  tel-out       3468650  359333468650
6   2021-05-31 14-33-18   1   sms-in           870           870
7   2021-05-31 15-06-28  55  tel-out     298869836  359298869836
8   2021-05-31 15-07-36   1   sms-in  359298869836  359298869836
9   2021-05-31 15-07-50  71  tel-out  359333182504  359333182504
10  2021-05-31 15-13-18  22  tel-out       3182504  359333182504
```